# Routing not working for me in Meteor with the help of FlowRouter

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I am trying to apply routing with the help of flow router package. But it is not working for me as what I had expected. I will share my code, please let me know where I am going wrong! Thanks in Advance.

```
FlowRouter.route('/',{
     name:'home',
     action(){
           BlazeLayout.render("HomeLayout");
     }
});

FlowRouter.route('/test',{
     name:'test',
     action(){  
         BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout',{main:'Test'});
     }
});
```

And I am getting following error when I go to `localhost:3000/test`.

```
modules-runtime.js:36Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './main.html'

Exception in defer callback: Error: Expected template or null, found: undefined
at ._render (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=65db8b6a8e3fca189b416de702967b1cb83d57d5:61:13)
at doRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2027:25)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1875:20
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3687:12)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1873:29
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2214:12)
at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1872:18)
at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:339:36)
at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:229:10)
at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:604:11)
```

Please tell me where I am wrong? Do I need to make any changes in my code?

Here is my index.html  file code :

```
<head>
  <title>intermediate-meteor</title>
</head>
```

Here is my MainLayout.html:

```
<template name="MainLayout">
    <header>
        <h1>My Recipe Book</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        {{>Template.dyanamic template=main}}
    </main>
</template>

<template name="Test">
    <h1>Test Template Rendering form Main Template...!!</h1>
</template>
```

Here is my HomeLayout.html:

```
<template name="HomeLayout">
    <header>
        <h1>My Recipe Book</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="billboard">
            <h2>Organize your meals</h2>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

Package.jason file code:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.12                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.10            # Reactive variable for tracker
jquery@1.11.9                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.2.0   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@1.2.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.14                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.5.8              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.2.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command



kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
```

Please go through my code and tell me where i am doing a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Your `index.html` file is the one that needs the dynamic Template:  `index.html`

```
<head>
  <title>intermediate-meteor</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> layout}}
</body>

<template name="layout">
   {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</template>
```

Then you can control what template gets loaded from what URL in the routes.

---

So at the end, your routes should look like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout', { main: 'MainLayout' });
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/test', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout', { main: 'Test' });
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/home', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout', { main: 'HomeLayout' });
  }
});
```

I have my HTML setup with an `index.html` file that only load the main template:

```
<body>
  {{> layout}}
</body>

<template name="layout">
   {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</template>
```

Then I create a new HTML file for each template:  `test.html`

```
<template name="test">
   <h1>Hello, this is a test page</h1>
</template>
```

And of course, your `homelayout` template in another file:   `homelayout.html`

```
<template name="homelayout">
   <h1>Hello, this is the home page</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: well i have created MainLayout.html which is my main template.  then i have created HomeLayout.html  and i have index.html to i have created an template in MainLayout.html with the name "Test" and i write the code for routing in route.js according to the flow-route that i am using in my project but it is not working for me the way i want..! You can share you completed code ?? Sorry i am new to Meteor so i am still not getting where i am going wrong..!!

Comment: I am also getting one error "install.js:101Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './main.html'"  i do not know why so?  where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you have both `kadira:flow-router` and `kadira:blaze-layout` installed?  Maybe add your HTML files to your post so we can see them.

Comment: Yes  i have installed both the packages form atmospherejs .com and it is showing in package..json file as well but i do not know why it is not working correctely..!!

Comment: Can you add the html files to the post?

Comment: well i have added all the code to the post please go through it .

Comment: I edited my answer to show specifically what you need to do. The `Template.dynamic` needs to be in the index.html file only. Then you can load up the other templates by their name in the routes.

Comment: Hello whatever you said i already did this.. :) but i am writing my test template in my main layout if you can see from my code i want to render this test template from my main layout :) but i do not know how to render this test template the routing code doesn't work for me :) now you understand me what i want to do ? :) ..!!

Comment: and i am still getting this error 
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './main.html'

 how to solve this one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122249/discussion-between-pranay-sute-and-tic).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you deleted the default client/main.html file.  Did you update the "import './main.html'" line in client/main.js ?

Comment: I just change the name of the file from mian.html to index.html.

Comment: I am learning Meteor too and have not gone through the documentation of FlowRouter.  If you change the name of the file from main.html to index.html?  Did you do the same inside the client/main.js ?

Comment: No .. and i am learning meteor js form tutorials and i follow levelup intermediate tutorials for learning Meteor js. In that tutorials if you can see he created two layouts like "MainLayout.html" and "HomeLayout.html" and then he create test template in MainLayout,html and using flowrouter he access that test template but with me it is not so . I will share the link you can see it and then let me know how it is possible. Please share your thoughts Thanks.

Here is the link :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOJ0hfVo368&index=6&list=PLLnpHn493BHFYZUSK62aVycgcAouqBt7V

Comment: If you changed main.html to index.html, you should make the corresponding change inside the client/main.js file.  Give that a try and see if it get rid of that error.

Comment: Well i try this one also but this is also not working according to how i want it. hey if you also learning meteor and if you have tried routing in meteor will you please share your code  with me it may help me somehow for my solution. I am using FlowRouter package for routing if you are using any other package please let me know and share your code so it will help me out i want to learn routing in meteor. Thanks..!

Comment: As mentioned, I am new to Meteor.  When I was reading the guide on routing, somehow I missed the "Rendering based on the route" section.  So, I am not using blaze-layout.  I am not using any kind of layout at all.  My routes are very simple:

    FlowRouter.route('/tos', {
        action(params, queryParams) {
            Blaze.render(Template.templateName,
               document.getElementById('content'));
        }
    });

You may want to go back to the last working revision, or create another test application and see if you can figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: I follow the intermediate  tutorials on YouTube if you click on the intermediate tutorials on meteor site it will take you to the leveluptuts video tutorials i am doing the same as scott did on the tutorials but it is not working for me well i will find the solution somehow and will let you know..!! anyways thanks..!!